# adding custom attribute to category

Tags: magento2, attributes, custom-attributes, category-attribute, install-script

I'm trying to add a new custom image attribute for category, following the guide here "https://webkul.com/blog/add-custom-image-attribute-category-magento-2/comment-page-1/#comment-16835"

However, after I added these files under **`/app/code/[vendor]/[Module]/`**

Then run

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile  
php bin/magento setup:upgrade  
php bin/magento c:c c:f
```

but nothing shows up, and I cannot find the module on the list. Please help

Comment: you forgot to run `php bin/magento s:s:d`

Comment: I tried to run that, but it's still not showing. also, can not find the module from the list "php bin/magento module:status"

Comment: you have to register your own module first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own **custom module** wherein you can use the resources from the guide provided in a link included in your post.

Follow the steps below

> **registration.php**
>   app/code/Vendor/CustomModule/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_CustomModule',
    __DIR__
);
```

> module.xml
>   app/code/Vendor/CustomModule/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_CustomModule" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

Comment: This works, thanks a lot. After created the registration.php file, I had to delete the Vendor/Module/di.xml from the guide which was causing error, and replace the module.xml you provided. After that, just run setup:upgrade, and everything works now! Thanks, i'm new to creating modules.

Comment: Can you show me how to call the image in the front end?

Comment: it's on the comment: 
Please follow below steps in order to get image url at frontend.
create instance of class Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository
then get category model by calling get method like
$category = $categoryRepository->get($categoryId, $storeId);
$imageUrl = “magento_media_url_path”.”catalog/category/”.$category->getCustomImage();
And then you can use this $imageUrl in your custom category page or as per your design.